# How to cut up an image into a puzzle.

Tags: shapes, clipping-mask

I'm trying to create a puzzle out of an image using a vector image I picked up from Adobe stock. However, when I create the clipping mask of the shape and the image it turns the entire puzzle into one big image instead of cutting the image up into each puzzle piece. Any suggestions? I am probably doing it wrong and would love the help.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to duplicate the image each time and make a new clipping mask. This would result in a MASSIVE file, fortunately for us Jongware has made a wonderful script to do this automatically!

[Download it here](http://www.jongware.com/binaries/puzzlify.zip) and then you can use it to create puzzles easily!

[image]